# Oracle Append Values Based Existing Value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of partial docket numbers.

```
docket_number
-------------
08DR2197
17JV1398
98JV2954
84JS249
76JV16391
66JV1616
```

If the docket number begins with a 6, 7, 8, or 9 then insert a "19" to the beginning of the docket number.  If the docket number begins with anything else, then insert a "20" to the beginning of the docket number.  Results would look like this.

```
docket_number
-------------
2008DR2197
2017JV1398
1998JV2954
1984JS249
1976JV16391
1966JV1616
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this option:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET docket_number = CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (docket_number, '^[6-9]')
                         THEN '19' ELSE '20' END || docket_number;
```

I am using a regex approach to check the first digit.  The option given by @Littlefoot might actually outperform this, but the above code is a bit more concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when substr(docket_number, 1, 1) in ('6', '7', '8', '9') then '19'
            else '20'
       end || docket_number as docket_number
from your_table
```

Comment: Short and pretty!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use string comparisons:

```
update t
    set docket_number = (case when docket_number >= '60' and docket_number <= '99'
                              then '19' else '20'
                         end) || docket_number;
```